# Efficient way to delete old log files on Windows 16 server?

Tags: windows, powershell, logging, server

I have over 10 TB of log file data. I want to find an efficient way to delete log files that are older than 3 years old. Originally, I was thinking about scheduling this PowerShell script:

```
# Delete all Files in PATH older than 3 years (1095 days) old
$Path = "Path to log files"
$Daysback = "-1095"

$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)
Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } | Remove-Item
```

I am concerned that looping through 10 TB of data will take hours to run even thought this script appears to run on O(n). Does anybody have any better solution?

Comment: The space the files occupy is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is the number of files.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many files

Comment: I suggest to take away the quotes around `-1095` and set `$DateToDelete` to `$CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback).Date` to set it to midnight. Also, add switch `-File` to the Get-Childitem to make sure you are only dealing with files, not directories.

Comment: Why not use `AddYear(-3)` instead of `AddDays`?

Answer (score 1):

If performance matters I'd get rid of pipes and wouldn't use gci (use lower level types from System.IO). If there are millions of files I'd also write it in c# and only call methods from ps runtime. Below is example to remove files older than N days:

```bsh
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"

public static class LogCleaner {

  public static void Clean(string dirName, int age)
  {

    foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirName))
    {
      var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
      if (fi.LastWriteTime < System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-age))
      {
        fi.Delete();
      }
    }
  }

}

"@

[LogCleaner]::Clean("C:\Temp\demo", 10)
```

You may also check how to achive this using windows native utilities (like dir), or maybe install git bash and try to do this linux way (e.g. using find command)